# Difference between 2 text files with uknown size

Tags: python

In hope to find a solution, I lost couple of days but no success! I have two text files with many lines. One file can contains thousands lines with numbers, for example: 79357795
79357796
68525650.

The second file also contains numbers, but not too much, maybe one hundred of lines (again one number per line). I tried some "algorithms" but no success. Now, my questions is: Can I check first line from first file with all lines from second file, after that, to check second line from first file with all lines from second file and so on up to the end of the file? And as a result, I want to save the difference between this two files in third files. Thank you all for responses and sorry for my baddest english. :)

PS: Oh yes, I need to do this in Python.

More details:
first_file.txt contains:

```
79790104
79873070
69274656
69180377
60492209
78177852
79023241
69736256
68699620
79577311    
78509545
69656007
68188871
60643247
78898817
79924105
79684143    
79036022
69445507
60605544
79348181
69748018
69486323
69102802
68651099
```

second_file.txt contain:

```
78509545    
69656007    
68188871    
60643247
78898817    
79924105    
79684143    
79036022    
69445507
60605544    
79348181    
69748018    
69486323    
69102802
68651099
79357794
78953958
69350610
78383111
68629321
78886856
```

third_file.txt need to contain what number not exist in first_file.txt but exist in second file, in this case:

```
79357794
78953958
69350610
78383111
68629321
78886856
```

Comment: It's hard to find out what you're trying to achieve. Please post some small example files and the expected output.

Comment: You may want to look into `set` functions, by loading all values into two sets, you can get intersection, union, etc - as in http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set

Comment: What do you mean by 'compare' and 'difference' in this case? If the first file has `79357795 79357796 68525650` for example and the second file only has one number, how are you comparing these? By sum? By text matching? Line by line? More detail needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

Edit: This will give you all numbers that are in both lists (which is what you first asked for.) See other answers for what your data set wants. (I Like 1_CR's answer.)

```
with open('firstfile.txt') as f:
    file1 = f.read().splitlines()

with open('secondfile.txt') as f:
    file2 = f.read().splitlines()

for x in file1:
    for y in file2:
        if x == y:
            print "Found matching: " + x
            #do what you want here
```

It could be made more efficient, but the files don't sound that big, and this is the simplest way.

Comment: Won't work. Once you have iterated over `file2`, it's over and you'll have to re-open  it.

Comment: No... file1 and file2 are a list of lines, not files. I used read() on the file objects.

Comment: The OP is asking for items in the second but not in the first, not items that are in both.  This is also horribly inefficient.

Comment: Oops, sorry, misread that.

Comment: "Can I check first line from first file with all lines from second file, after that, to check second line from first file with all lines from second file and so on up to the end of the file?" That is what the OP said first. Who cares if it takes 1 second vs .5 seconds?

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
from itertools import ifilterfalse

with open('first') as fst, open('second') as snd, open('not_second', 'w') as fout:
    snd_nums = set(int(line) for line in snd)
    fst_not_in_snd = ifilterfalse(snd_nums.__contains__, (int(line) for line in fst))
    fout.writelines(num + '\n' for num in fst_not_in_snd)
```

Comment: The OP states that `snd` is much shorter than `fst` - couldn't some efficiencies be gained by changing your `ifilterfalse` to be iterating over `snd` instead of `fst`?  Or is the real bottleneck the `__contains__`?

Comment: @ernie it's easiest to put the shortest, and the comparision to in memory, then pick the lines from the main file

Comment: Meaning that the performance impact of iterating over lots of items is less than the memory costs of comparing against a large set?  I would guess the reality is that it depends on the relative sizes, but was just curious . . .

Comment: @ernie actually I think I got it the wrong way around - misread the `not` in the OP's question...

Answer (score 0):

Well, if i were you, I would load those files into two [lists](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html), and then iterate through one of them, looking up each value in second one.

Comment: Since they're looking for items in the 2nd, which are not in the 1st, and as the 2nd is much smaller, you'd probably want to iterate through that one, checking for matches in the first.

Comment: 1) "One" != "First", it's OP's decision which one to chose
2) OP edited question after I posted an answer. There were no data in original one.

Comment: I wasn't making that assumption, but was just adding a point of clarification for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

If the files are small enough to load into memory, sets are an option

```
with open('firstfile.txt') as f1, open('second_file.txt') as f2:
    print '\n'.join(set(f2.read().splitlines()).difference(f1.read().splitlines()))
```